# Android N unable to stop my app for Multi-Window

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-7.0-nougat

After using `android:resizableActivity="false"` in my application manifest, when building the application shows:

> Error:(22) No resource identifier found for attribute 'resizableActivity' in package 'android'.

Comment: Do you have `compileSdkVersion 24` in `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 1):

The attribute [is `android:resizeableActivity`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#resizeableActivity), not `android:resizableActivity` (note the `e` after the `z`).